# how to find next order id mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample input

```
order_id Customer_id Order_date    
1          1         2017-11-01    
2          2         2017-11-02    
3          1         2017-11-03    
4          2         2017-11-04
```

Desired Output

```
order_id next_order_id

1              3    
2              4    
3    
4
```

Comment: What will the "next_order_id" for order_id : 3 and 4??? NULL or something else

Comment: @KKK NULL.......

Comment: MySQL version please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`LEAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead):

```
SELECT order_id,
 LEAD(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_id ORDER BY Order_date) AS next_order
FROM tab
ORDER BY order_id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo - MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce309862f07ec9f2765f9d18c99bf2ab)**

---

For previous MySQL version:

```
SELECT order_id,
     (SELECT order_id 
     FROM tab t2 
     WHERE t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id 
       and t2.Order_date > t1.order_date 
     ORDER BY Order_date LIMIT 1 ) AS next_order
FROM tab t1
ORDER BY order_id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=674bebbfb0d58824c55ee2426b927d6a)**

Comment: Windowing functions take all the fun out of it :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can also `subquery` :

```
SELECT order_id, 
       (select order_id 
        from table 
        where Customer_id = t.Customer_id and 
              Order_date > t.Order_date
        order by Order_date 
        LIMIT 1) as next_order_id
FROM table t
ORDER BY order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way in MySQL would be a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.order_id
        from t t2
        where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id and t2.order_date > t.order_date
        order by t2.order_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as next_order_id
from t;
```

If you are using MySQL 8.0, then `lead()` is a better choice.